# Who, or what, is Tsunku san?

Tags: translation, culture

Saw this on twitter.

つんくさん！いただきます！

http://lockerz.com/s/121213710

What does that mean?

Comment: This is a question about a Japanese person, not the Japanese language.  In any case, simply googling for 「つんく」would have answered your question.  Please do a bit of research before posting your questions here.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[He](http://www.tsunku.net/) is a rock musician, and is the person who created the idol group `モーニング娘。`. He seems to have appeared in [a TV commercial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ga-jpFONIic). `いただきます` is the greeting word said before meal, or occasionally before drinking, as in this case.

Comment: He's even on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsunku